# Match any character but no empty and not only white spaces

Tags: regex

I have this regex:

```
\[tag\](.*?)\[\/tag\]
```

It match any character between two tags. The problem that is matching also empty contents or just white spaces inside the tags, for example:

```
[tag][/tag]
[tag]  [/tag]
```

How can I avoid it? Make it to match at least 1 character and not only white spaces. Thanks!

Comment: If the tag content always starts with an alphanumeric character, you can use a word boundary: `\[tag\]\s*(\b.*?)\[\/tag\]`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
\[tag\](?!\s*\[\/tag\])(.*?)\[\/tag\]
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/SeAJGU/1) and the [Regulex graph](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5C%5Btag%5C%5D(%3F!%5Cs*%5C%5B%5C%2Ftag%5C%5D)(.*%3F)%5C%5B%5C%2Ftag%5C%5D):

[image]

The `(?!\s*\[\/tag\])` is a negative lookahead that fails the match if, immediately to the right of the current location, there is 0+ whitespaces, `[/tag]`.

Comment: way too complicated

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk But is the only way here. Probably, `\[tag\](?!\s*\[)(.*?)\[\/tag\]` will also do, but is less precise.

Comment: @KirillPolishchuk [Your regex does not work correctly](https://regex101.com/r/09TRWU/2).

Comment: Thanks for the reply, may I know how did you generate this explanatory image?

Comment: @Keaire There is a link to Regulex in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You might change your expression to something similar to [this](https://regex101.com/r/k7I9cl/1/):

```
\[tag\]([\s\S]+)\[\/tag\]
```

[image]

and you might add a quantifier to it, and bound it with number of chars, similar to [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/3grbAu/1):

```
\[tag\]([\s\S]{3,})\[\/tag\]
```

[image]

Or you could do the same with your original expression as [this expression](https://regex101.com/r/4QEcng/1/): 
[image]

Answer (score 1):

Try this [regex](https://regex101.com/r/09TRWU/3):

```
\[(tag)\](?!\s*\[\/\1\])(.*?)\[\/\1\]
```

This regex matches `tag` only if it has at least one non-whitespace char.

Answer (score 1):

If this is a PCRE (or php) or NP++ or Perl, use this

`(?s)(?:\[tag\]\s*\[/tag\](*SKIP)(?!)|\[tag\]\s*(.+?)\s*\[/tag\])`

https://regex101.com/r/aCsOoQ/1

If not, you're stuck with using Stribnetz regex, which works because of
an odd condition of your requirements.

Readable

```
 (?s)
 (?:
      \[tag\]
      \s* 
      \[/tag\]
      (*SKIP) 
      (?!)
   |  
      \[tag\]
      \s* 
      ( .+? )                       # (1)
      \s* 
      \[/tag\]
 )
```